# What's a good tool to jailbreak iPad mini?

Tags: ipad, jailbreak

I just bought myself an iPad mini and I'm wondering what is a good tool to use to jailbreak it and hopefully without breaking the device. I've heard a couple names like Evasi0n and Redsn0w but am unsure of their reliability. So, what's a good and safe tool to use to jailbreak it?

Comment: Consider being explicit about what "good" and "safe" mean. To some, good might mean they can control your device - to others, it's cheap or free, to others it's the quality of the support and documentation or how long it takes the jailbreak to work after each update gets released by Apple.

Comment: I'm generally looking for something that works and safe meaning that it doesn't damage the iPad since I just bought it and I'm not tech-savvy so it'd be a hassle if it breaks. So maybe something that doesn't cause malfunction, and would be an added bonus if they wouldn't be able to control the device.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend anyone jailbreak their device if they don't understand how to re-secure the OS properly. Basically, when you know how everything works, you have a chance of knowing that the lock you just removed from the front door isn't needed since you have a locked screen door or you have placed a lock on the rooms in the house you want secured. I'd stick with Apple's OS unmodified if you want good and secure and jailbreak on an iPod touch until you've learned how to secure things yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use evasi0n - it is fully compatible with the iOS 6 and hence the iPad Mini. The process if fully automatic. More about how to jailbreak here: [How to jailbreak iPhone, iPad or iPod Touch running iOS6?](http://www.copytrans.net/support/jailbreak-iphone-ipad-ipod-touch-ios6/)

Answer (score -2):

If you are running iOS 5, use Absynthe instead.

Comment: The iPad mini is not capable of running iOS 5.